# Is the strong topology on $B(H)$ first countable?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, first-countable

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and consider the strong operator topology (SOT) on $B(H)$, that is the topology on $B(H)$ generated by the seminorms
$$p_x: u \mapsto \Vert ux \Vert, \quad x\in H$$

Is this topology first countable?

**Attempt:** It suffices to find a countable neighborhood basis of $0$. Let $(x_n)_n$ be a dense sequence of $H$. Then I believe the topology generated by $$u \mapsto \Vert u x_n \Vert, \quad n \geq 1$$
agrees with SOT. Hence, the collection
$$\left\{\bigcap_{i=1}^k p_{x_{n_i}}^{-1}([0, \epsilon[): k \geq 1; n_1, \dots, n_k \geq 1, \epsilon \in \Bbb{Q}\cap(0, \infty) \right\}$$
is a countable basis of $0$ of $SOT$.

Is the above proof outline correct?

EDIT: This question was accidentally closed by a misunderstanding. Please read the comments and reopen the question. Thanks!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2515140/metrizability-of-the-strong-operator-topology-on-the-set-of-unitary-operators-of?rq=1

Comment: The topology you mention is not the same as the strong topology.  Pointwise convergence on a dense set is not the same as pointwise convergence, unless you are restricted to a uniformly  bounded set.

Comment: I think the closure of this question is inapropriate because it has NOT been answered in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664222/the-strong-topology-on-u-mathcal-h-is-metrisable.  In fact the latter deals with $U(H)$ while the OP here deals with $B(H)$.  Their difference is so relevant that one question has an affirmative answer and the other has a negative one.  I was about to answer by proving that $B(H)$ is not first countable but was prevented from doing so by the closure.

Comment: @Sumanta, I disagree.  If you allow me to post an answer I can prove that the strong topology on $B(H)$ is nof first countable, even though its restriction to **bounded** sets is metrizable.

Comment: Note that $H$ is assumed to be seperable.

Comment: We're talking about first countability of $B(H)$ rather than $H$.

Comment: The point is that $H$ has no countable **Hamel** basis, even though it has a countable **Schauder** basis.

Comment: Look at the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664222/the-strong-topology-on-u-mathcal-h-is-metrisable People here assumed separable means countable Schauder basis. Please check the definition of separability here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112914/discussion-between-ruy-and-sumanta).

Comment: HanulJeon,  an4s, JoséCarlosSantos please reopen the question. The link I have shared to close the question is not appropriate and @Ruy trying to post a solution. Please excuse me.

Comment: Thanks for trying to reopen. I thought already I was missing something.

Comment: @user745578 Please edit your question also if you want.

Comment: In case anyone is curious, and while the question remains closed, here is a NEGATIVE answer to this question: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HDbwmbFcMSAKB4xteO7HRXPEK3J9ZJzS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Nice. A typo, $U:=\{T\in B(H):||Ty||<1\}$ will be $V:=\{T\in B(H):||Ty||<1\}.$

Comment: We need one more reopen vote. I'm sure that will happen. Thanks already!

Comment: Thanks to everyone involved.  All's Well That Ends Well !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Theorem**.  If  $H$ is an infinite dimensional Hilbert space  then the strong topology on $B(H)$ is **not** first countable.

*Proof*. Suppose by way contradiction that $B(H)$ is first countable and hence we may pick  a countable neighborhood basis
of the zero operator, say $\{U_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$.  For each $n$, choose a neighborhood $V_n$ of  zero of the form
$$
  V_n=\{T\in B(H): \Vert T(x^n_i)\Vert <\varepsilon ^n_i,  \ i=1, 2, \ldots , k_n\},
  $$
with $V_n\subseteq U_n$,
where the $x^n_i$ are vectors in $H$ and the $\varepsilon ^n_i$ are positive real numbers.

Let $X$ denote the set formed by all of the $x^n_i$ showing up in the above descriptions of all of the $V_n$,    clearly
a  countable set.

Since $H$ is infinite dimensional, its (Hamel) dimension is uncountable (regardless of $H$ being separable or not), so
the linear span of $X$  (no closure) is a proper subset of $H$.
Fixing a vector $y$ in $H\setminus \text{span}(X)$, consider the neighborhood of zero given by
$$
  V=\{T\in B(H): \Vert T(y)\Vert <1\}.
  $$
Given that   $\{U_n\}_{n\in {\mathbb N}}$ is a  neighborhood basis for zero, there ought to be some $n$ such that $U_n\subseteq V$, and
hence also that $V_n\subseteq V$.

Interpreting the last inclusion we see that for every bounded linear operator $T$ on $H$ one has that
$$
  \Vert T(x^n_i)\Vert <\varepsilon ^n_i,\ \forall i=1, 2, \ldots , k_n \quad \Rightarrow \quad\Vert T(y)\Vert <1.
  $$

Observing that  $y$ is not in the span of
$\{x^n_i:   i=1, 2, \ldots , k_n\}$, (it is not  even in $\text{span}(X)$), we may easily construct a
bounded operator $T$ such that $T(x^n_i)=0$, for all $i$, while $\Vert T(y)\Vert =1$, and this operator contradicts the above  implication.
QED.

---

**Remarks**:  Assuming WLOG that we choose the vector $y$ in the above proof with $\Vert y\Vert = 1$, the operator $T$ with smallest norm satisfying the above conditions has norm equal to
$$
  {1 \over \text{dist}\big(y, \text{span}\{x^n_i:   i=1, 2, \ldots , k_n\}\big)}.
  $$
Therefore this will explode with $n$ in case
the span of
$\{x^n_i:   i=1, 2, \ldots , k_n\}$ gets too close to $y$.

This fact is behind  the reason why the strong topology is not first countable on $B(H)$ despite being
**metrizable**, and hence also
**first countable**, when  restricted to a bounded subset of $B(H)$, such as the set $U(H)$ of
all unitary operators (cf. [The strong topology on $U(\mathcal H)$ is metrisable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1664222/the-strong-topology-on-u-mathcal-h-is-metrisable)).